# Is it a limitation of the JDK that I cannot view, in the debugger, lambda-captured reference values?

Tags: java, debugging, lambda, java-8

Is it possible to view the values of lambda-captured values (whether primitive or reference) in a Java debugger?  (If so, which one(s)?)

(It is apparently not possible in IntellJ IDEA.  Obviously I can see those values by copying to a local variable in the lambda, but I'm trying to learn if it is a missing feature of IDEA or of the Oracle JDK; I'm not trying to rag on JetBrains.)

(I'm hoping this isn't considered an inappropriate product-related question.  Let me know how to ask it properly if you think so, so I can learn how to use SO.)

Comment: you should compile with debaug enabled. [How?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Consider using the latest version of eclipse (I think named luna) which is supposed to have complete support for java 8 features, which I assume, but have not actually confirmed, to include debugging through lambdas.

Comment: Yes, eclipse does allow you to view captured variables.